# Magento2: How to install an external package without composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, autoloader

I have some packages installed under the `vendor` dir.
Now, I need a way to take one of them out & place it somewhere else that'll allow editing the files (same as moving a Magento module to `app/code`, but in this case it's an external library & not a Magento module).
I tried to place it under `lib` & under `lib/internal` + some other similar variations, but nothing seems to work & I get a `Class ... does not exist` error when I use classes from this library.
-- Any idea how to make it work (without changing the files or other files)?

Comment: You have raised a good point. +1